# Blurry font from google fonts

Tags: html, css

I am using a font from google fonts and for some reason its coming out blurry compared to a default font. I am not sure if it is just my computer. Is there any way I can fix the blurriness?

[image: side-by-side comparison of the two fonts]

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Zilla Slab', serif;
  font-size: 88px;
  line-height: 90px;
  color: #262421;
}

.joe {
  font-family: serif;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Arimo&family=Zilla+Slab:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <h1 class="joe">Hello</h1>
</body>
```

I tried using a font from Google Fonts, but it is coming out blurry. I expected it to come out at a good resolution.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Have you tried it in different browsers?

Comment: Perhaps tweaking with `text-rendering` might work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-rendering. But this seems like an issue with how the font was designed at the first place.

Comment: Incorrect order of CSS: your local CSS should be placed AFTER the Google Fonts external CSS. Also, have you accidentally zoomed in on your browser? I got no problem displaying a sharp font using your snippet in macOS.

Comment: @TheBlckbird I am using the latest version of chrome (Version 114.0.5735.134). I have not tried it on different browsers.

Comment: @Raptor I corrected this, but it doesn't seem like the font was affected. I did not zoom in on my browser. Maybe it is just my computer.

Comment: I see a sharp font on my laptop, Windows10/Edge.

Comment: I see a sharp font in iMac, macOS Ventura 13.3.1, Brave 1.52 / Chromium 114.0.5735.134 (same as OP's version). I even zoomed in on the browser, still sharp.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with CSS `text-shadow` property like this:

```css
h1{
    font-family: 'Zilla Slab', serif;
    font-size: 88px;
    line-height: 90px;
    color: #262421;
  }

  h1.test{
    background: #28ff86;
  }

  .joe {
    font-family: serif;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Arimo&family=Zilla+Slab:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="test" style="text-shadow: 0 0 0 #262421;">Hello</h1>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <h1 class="joe">Hello</h1>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The `h1:nth-child(1)` is not applied to the "Hello" wordings at all. The `<h1>` has no child.

Comment: please check the Developer Console. The CSS is not applied.

Comment: @Prince the nth-child stuff is not applied because the first h1 is actually the 3rd child of the body in your snippet because there are a couple of link elements between it and the body tag. nth-of-type would do it - or format things more 'correctly' by putting those links in the head element.

Comment: Please look at the actual code being created by the snippet as @Raptor suggested. You will see the body tag comes before the link tags. If you had put the links in a head element then all would be well, but you didn't.

Comment: Now, check updated answer.

Comment: `text-shadow` does no effect at all. If you toggle the CSS property in Developer Tools, you will notice no difference at all. OP's problem is probably due to client settings (either browser or OS, or both).

Answer (score 1):

I carried out tests and comparisons between the font used in the HTML page and the rendering of Google Fonts. I also installed the font locally for further comparison. **The font always shows a slight blurring in all cases**.

Tests carried out on MacOS using Firefox, Safari and Chrome.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Arimo&family=Zilla+Slab:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        
        <style>
            h1 {
                color: black;
                font-family: 'Zilla Slab', serif;
                font-size: 100px;
                font-weight: 700;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm just going to switch to a very similar font to get a better resolution.